# Image Buttons Kivy

Tags: python, linux, windows, kivy

Trying to call vsOpen from ImageButton inside LauncherApp();the goal was to make buttons that have images on them that respond to input. Calling VsOpen says I'm missing self as an argument if self is then placed in I receive "ImageButton has no attribute self". As you can see below I have normal buttons working however I can not seem to properly create a button image. Would someone care to explain how I would go about this?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout 
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from colorama import Fore, Style
import webbrowser as browser
import subprocess
import os

PATHs=[#other_program_names/locations_go_here]

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):  
            def on_press(self):  
                for x in range(0, 2):
                    iD=Fernet.generate_key()
                    cipher = Fernet(iD)
                    url = input(">")
                    crypt_url=cipher.encrypt(bytes(url, "utf-8"))
                    if url != "":
                        if url.startswith("www.", 0,4):
                            dcrypt_url=cipher.decrypt(bytes(crypt_url))
                            browser.open_new_tab(dcrypt_url)
                            print(Fore.BLUE+"Accessing " + url + "..")
                        else:
                            print("String given was not a url")
                            quit
                    else:
                        print(Fore.RED+">no url was entered..")
                        quit

            def vsOpen(self):
                try:
                    if os.path.isfile(PATHs[0]) == 1:
                        self.x=subprocess.call(PATHs[0])
                    else:
                        print(Fore.RED+"vsCode was not found"+Style.BRIGHT)
                except TypeError:
                    print("Type error has occured at vsOpen")
                    quit


        class LauncherApp(App):
            def build(self):
                layout=FloatLayout(size=(200,200))
                #Normal Buttons were here
                layout.add_widget(ImageButton.vsOpen())
                layout.add_widget(ImageButton.on_press())
                return layout

root = LauncherApp()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.run()
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: I think I got it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
layout.add_widget(ImageButton.vsOpen())
```

I'm not sure what you expect this to do, but it makes no sense. `vsOpen` is a method of the ImageButton class, you should only call it from a class instance, not the class itself (unless you know what you are doing and have a *really* good reason).

Even if this ran the method somehow, it doesn't return a widget that you could add to the layout, so it's unclear what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I re-edited the code so hopefully it's more clear. I'm trying to create buttons with images on them I had normal buttons working on the previous edit and was able to call on_press from `layout.add_widget(ImageButton.on_press())` when `return layout` is called but was unable to call `layout.add_widget.(ImageButton.vsOpen())` and wanted to know if there was a way to properly fix this in order to add multiple buttons with images on them.

Comment: @RVN I'm afraid nothing has changed, your code makes absolutely no sense. Even `layout.add_widget(ImageButton.on_press())` shouldn't actually work, and I can't tell what you even intend it to do.